# UIPopoverController displayed as modalViewController in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, modalviewcontroller

I just ran into a very frustrating problem. I don't know if it's an iOS8 bug or it's something else.

I'm loading the view from a nib, which looks like this:

[image: popover view in interface builder]

Here ist my code:

```
UIViewController *popoverViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[popoverViewController setView:poppverViewFromNib];

_popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverViewController];
[_popverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(100, 100, 10, 10) inView:[self view] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

The iOS simulator as well as the real device are displaying the viewController modally like you can see here:

[image: presentation on the device]

**EDIT**

As requested in comments, I tell you what I expect when using `UIPopoverController`:
I expect an UIPopover, not a modalViewController.

So here my question to all of those how didn't get it: Why does my `UIPopoverController` does not display as a popover but as modalViewController? How can I fix it?

Comment: What are you expecting to achieve? You need to edit your question with expected result.

Comment: I expect an UIPopover. Don't you know, how that looks like? I'll edit my question, but it's unnecessary I think. This is not what an UIPopover looks like!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation. Popover presentation is only available for horizontally regular size classes. Currently, this is only on iPad. Popover presentation on iPhone will always be executed as full screen modal presentation. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIModalPresentationPopover).

You are lucky that iOS8 doesn't crash, as iOS7 and below, if you used `UIPopoverController` on a phone idiom, your app would crash. `UIPopoverController` is deprecated in iOS8 in favor of popover modal presentation. This is why your app does not crash.

Comment: Shame on me... I didn't remember this and might have googled wrong. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the same code for UIPopoverController  as iOS 7

just set ViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 290);
It will work.

Other Solution
iOS 8 has a new PopOverController called UIPopoverPresentationController

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Terms_NC"];

navController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 290);

// Present the view controller using the popover style.
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
[self presentViewController:navController animated: YES completion: nil];



// Get the popover presentation controller and configure it.
UIPopoverPresentationController *presentationController =
[navController popoverPresentationController];
presentationController.permittedArrowDirections =0;
presentationController.sourceView = self.view;
presentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 340);
```

Comment: That sounds really interesting... I gonna test it soon, thanks for the hint!